# $.inArray not worting on object JavaScript object any alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

i am working on object from which i want to remove a value on specific address.
i need the position of element and want to remove it from object

here is the code :

```
var matches =  {
     "users-email": "email", 
     "users-activated": "activated", 
     "users-created_at": "created_at", 
     "users-registration_page": "registration_page", 
     "profiles-firstname": "firstname"
} ;
var option = 'firstname';

var if_in = $.inArray(option, matches );
//console.log(matches)
if( if_in !== -1 )
{
    matches.splice(if_in, 1);
}

$.each(matches , function(i,v){
   $('.test').append(v+'<br>');
});
```

in my object `$.inArray()` not working it return -1 .

can someone help me to find this issue .

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/n28keL90/)

Comment: your matches variable is an object, not an array.

Comment: @Alexander That will only work if option is the key. In this case it is the value

Comment: `$.inArray` only works on arrays.  `matches` isn't an array.

Comment: @Haseeb - so youve used `$.inArray` previously, so what? In this case it wont do what you're hoping (expecting?)

Comment: `$.inArray not worting on object` No, it isn't, what makes you think it should?

Comment: I can't even.... inArray doesn't work on an object. Dog bites man! If the function was called inObject, we'd have a real question here. It isn't, so we don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrected answer to delete by value. You can use $.each to iterate over the object and delete the matching value.

```
$.each (matches, function(key, value) {
   if (value == option) {
      delete matches[key];
      return false; //deleted matching value
   }
});
```

to delete multiple keys by value,

```
var keysToDelete = [];
for (var key in matches) {
   if (matches[key] == option) {
      keysToDelete.push(key);
   }
};

for (var i = 0; i < keysToDelete.length; i++ ) {
   if (matches.hasOwnProperty(keysToDelete[i])) {
      delete matches[keysToDelete[i]];
   }
}
```

Comment: Because this doesn't solve the question.  He's searching for a *value*, not key.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check if your option matches a value, simplest way would be to iterate through each property and check the values that way

```
var matches =  {"users-email": "email", "users-activated": "activated", "users-created_at": "created_at", "users-registration_page": "registration_page", "profiles-firstname": "firstname"} ;
var option = 'firstname';

for (var key in matches) {
    if (matches[key] === option) {
        alert ("IN");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're checking against the value and not the key; maybe something like this?

```
var key = undefined;
for(var i in matches) {
  if (matches[i] === option)  {key = i; break; }
}
if (key !== undefined) delete matches[key];
```

Comment: Might wanna `break;` after finding the `key`? :-P